# Dissallow access to all files except files from 2 directories and index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have this:

```
<Files *.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all 
</Files>

<Files index.php>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Besides index.php, how can I alow allow files from two other directories to be accessed by everyone?

The file structure is like this:

```
<dir1>
<dir2>
<dir3>
index.php
```

Only index.php, `<dir1>`, `<dir2` (all files in them) should be visible to all visitors

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite ([see documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)), By adding these lines to your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(dir1|dir2)/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This will throw a 403 forbidden error if someone tries to access files not in dir1 or dir2 or the index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an htaccess file in `<dir3>` and put this in it:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```